# It is possible with Zoom meeting to force all attendees to only view one attendee

Tags: video-streaming, zoom.us

If I am hosting a Zoom meeting, is it possible to configure it such that all attendees will ONLY be able to see a specific, single attendee's webcam or shared desktop?

Example. I invite a sales rep to a meeting with several potential clients. I want everyone to see the sales rep the whole time, and restrict their ability to see me, or see each other. Is this possible with zoom?

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of features in Zoom that can accomplish something similar to this.

However, your only option on the web client is to have people be muted with their video off.

Otherwise, on the desktop app, your best bet is to enable [focus mode](https://support.zoom.us/hc/en-us/articles/360061113751-Focus-mode), which hides the videos of other users in the meeting who are not host, cohost, or [spotlighted](https://support.zoom.us/hc/en-us/articles/201362653-Spotlighting-participants-videos). The host/cohost can still see everyone who has their video on.

For the sake of completeness, I’ll also mention that [Zoom Webinars](https://support.zoom.us/hc/en-us/articles/115005474943) are the one way attendees won’t be able to see who else is watching. However, this costs $700 per year for one license so it’s probably  not an option for anyone who’s not part of a large Zoom plan where other users will also be hosting webinars.